# C programming in Linux: not getting correct output for program that finds number of occurrences of substring in file

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a program that finds the number of occurrences of input substrings from the command line inside a text file (also read from the command line) which is written into a buffer.

When I run the code in bash, I get the error: Segmentation fault (core dumped). 
I am still learning how to code with C in this environment and have some sort of idea as to why the segmentation fault occurred (misuse of dynamic memory allocation?), but I could not find the problem with it. All I could conclude was that the problem is coming from within the for loop (I labeled where the potential error is being caused in the code).

EDIT: I managed to fix the segmentation fault error by changing `argv[j]` to `argv[i]`, however when I run the code now, count1 always returns 0 even if the substring occurs multiple times in the text file and I am not sure what is wrong even though I have gone through the code multiple times.

```
$ more foo.txt

aabbccc

$ ./main foo.txt a

0
```

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp; 
    long lsize; 
    char *buf;
    int count = 0, count1 = 0; 
    int i, j, k, l1, l2;   

    if (argc < 3) { printf("Error: insufficient arguments.\n"); return(1); };

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 

    if (!fp) { 
        perror(argv[1]); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    //get size of file 
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    lsize = ftell(fp); 
    rewind(fp);

    //allocate memory for entire content
    buf = calloc(1, lsize+1);

    if (!buf) { 
        fclose(fp); 
        fputs("Memory alloc fails.\n", stderr); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    //copy the file into the buffer
    if (1 != fread(buf, lsize, 1, fp)) {
        fclose(fp);
        free(buf); 
        fputs("Entire read fails.\n", stderr); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    l1 = strlen(buf);

    //error is somewhere here
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < l1;) {
            k = 0; 
            count = 0; 
            while ((&buf[j] == argv[k])) {
                count++;
                j++; 
                k++; 
            }
            if (count == strlen(argv[j])) {
                count1++; 
                count = 0; 
            }
            else
                j++; 
        }
        printf("%d\n", count1);
    }

    fclose(fp); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Not your problem but `while(j < l1)` is much clearer than `for (j = 0; j < l1;)`

Comment: `while ((&buf[j] == argv[k]))` aka `while(false)`

Comment: Debugging is an important skill to learn as a beginning programmer. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread(buf, lsize, 1, fp)` will read 1 block of `lsize` bytes, however `fread`
doesn't care about the contents and won't add a `'\0'`-terminating byte for the
string, so `l1 = strlen(buf);` yields undefined behaviour, the rest of the
result can be ignored as a result of this (and your counting has errors as well).
Note that files usually don't have a 0-terminating byte at the end,
that applies even for files containing text, they usually end with a
newline.

You have to set the 0-terminating byte yourself:

```
if (1 != fread(buf, lsize, 1, fp)) {
    fclose(fp);
    free(buf); 
    fputs("Entire read fails.\n", stderr); 
    exit(1); 
}

buf[lsize] = '0';
```

And you can use `strstr` to get the location of the substring, like this:

```
for(i = 2; i < argc; ++i)
{
    char *content = buf;
    int count = 0;

    while((content = strstr(content, argv[i])))
    {
        count++;
        content++; // point to the next char in the substring
    }

    printf("The substring '%s' appears %d time(s)\n", argv[i], count);

}
```

Your counting is wrong, there are some errors. This comparison

```
&buf[j] == argv[k]
```

is wrong, you are comparing pointers, not the contents. You have to use `strcmp`
to compare strings. In this case you would have to use `strncmp` because you
only want to match the substring:

```
while(strncmp(&buf[j], argv[k], strlen(argv[k])) == 0)
{
    // substring matched
}
```

but this is also wrong, because you are incrementing `k` as well, which will
give you the next argument, at the end you might read beyond the limits of
`argv` if the substring is longer than the number of arguments. Based on your
code, you would have to compare characters:

```
while(buf[j] == argv[i][k])
{
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

You would have to increment the `counter` only when a substring is matched, like
this:

```
l1 = strlen(buf);

for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    int k = 0; // running index for inspecting argv[i]
    for (j = 0; j < l1; ++j) {
        while(buf[j + k] == argv[i][k])
            k++;

        // if all characters of argv[i] 
        // matched, argv[i][k] will be the
        // 0-terminating byte
        if(argv[i][k] == 0)
            count++;

        // reset running index for argv[i]
        // go to next char if buf
        k = 0;
    }

    printf("The substring '%s' appears %d time(s)\n", argv[i], count);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. That was very informative considering I am still learning how to code properly.